# Angular: Check when Output Variable in Component Changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

How do I check if Output in Component changes? Then run another method

Here is Parent component,

After it gets data from Child, want to immediately run another event.

**Parent HTML:**

```
    <div>
        Address Type:* 
        <app-address-type-dropdown (selectedItemOutput) = "test"></app-address-type-dropdown>
    </div>
```

**Parent Typescript:**

Goal: When value is outputted, detect changes in this parent, and write console command.

```
export class AddressFormatheaderFormComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }
public test: any;

public sayHi(){
  console.log(this.test);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by creating another function, an event handler essentially. So when your child component `<app-address-type-dropdown>` emits a value, this event handler will take care of what to do next.

E.g. `onNewItemSelect($event)` is the event handler.

```html
<div>
  Address Type:* 
  <app-address-type-dropdown (selectedItemOutput)="onNewItemSelect($event)"></app-address-type-dropdown>
</div>
```

```js
export class AddressFormatheaderFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  public test: any;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onNewItemSelect(itemSelected){
     this.test = itemSelected;
     console.log(this.test);
     //do something else
  }
}
```

Do have read on this section of of [**Angular official docs on component interaction**](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need EventEmitter so in child component, when value changes, it will emit event and in parent component, it will detect changes and call parent function.

Something like let's say your child component.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-address-type-dropdown,
    template: `<button class='btn btn-primary' (click)="valueChanged()">Click me</button> `
})
export class AppAddressTypeDropdown{
    @Output() selectedItemOutput= new EventEmitter();
    Counter = 0;
    valueChanged() { // You can give any function name
        this.counter = this.counter + 1;
        this.selectedItemOutput.emit(this.counter);
    }
}
```

And in parent html, just try update call slightly. Please call any function to know when it changes.

```
<app-address-type-dropdown (selectedItemOutput) = "changeDetect($event)"></app-address-type-dropdown>

export class AddressFormatheaderFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  public test: any;

  public sayHi(){
    console.log(this.test);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  changeDetect(counter){
     console.log(counter);
     //do something here
  }
```